# Error building to Android Phone in debug

Tags: android

I created an app hello world in Android Studios
I set up my phone so that it was in debug mode and I could communicate
I ran helloworld on my phone!
It ran great.
Then I had issues on my computer and the files for helloworld got destroyed.
I then recreated a helloworld and tried to run on my phone. I got the following errors.

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: lge-nexus_5-076a60f4010aa338
Uploading file
local path: E:\Users\Spencer\AndroidStudioProjects\HELLOWORLD\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/s.s.helloworld
Installing s.s.helloworld
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/s.s.helloworld"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/s.s.helloworld
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]

DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall s.s.helloworld
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

I tried to remove the app on the phone. I reset the phone to factory settings. I even adb shell and looked for the app. I have found no signs of the app and I cant create apps of even different names on this phone anymore. I am new to android development and would hate to be unable to continue.

Comment: I have allowed USB debugging on my phone. Everything was working fine until the project got deleted and recreated

Comment: @user3956566 I have tried all of those options. The issue is whatever got messed up from the recreation of the project is preventing normal means. Is there somewhere I can turn on additional logic or something so that I can know why it is failing instead of just the generic message?